# compiler can't find zlib.h

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I am going to compile a GraphChi algorithm but I failed.

```
make example_apps/pagerank bin/example_apps/pagerank file example_apps/soc-LiveJournal1.txt niters 2
g++ -g -O3 -I/usr/local/include/ -I./src/  -fopenmp -Wall -Wno-strict-aliasing  -Iexample_apps/ example_apps/pagerank.cpp -o  bin/example_apps/pagerank -lz
```

the error message:

```
In file included from ./src/io/stripedio.hpp:50:0,
             from ./src/api/vertex_aggregator.hpp:42,
             from ./src/graphchi_basic_includes.hpp:43,
             from example_apps/pagerank.cpp:37:
./src/util/ioutil.hpp:35:18: fatal error: zlib.h: No such file or directory
#include <zlib.h>
              ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [example_apps/pagerank] Error 1
```

Comment: `sudo apt install zlib1g-dev`?